# Displaying a JSON Google Search in The LogCat

Tags: java, android, ajax, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get the search result from the URL

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=JSON

and displaying it into the LogCat using `log.v()`.

The problem is that instead of displaying the search results in the `LogCat`, the program keeps running non stop and what I see in the `LogCat` is an endless list of this

> 11-19 15:51:11.256: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 14% free 6651K/7688K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
>
> 11-19 15:51:11.264: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 14% free 6651K/7688K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
>
> 11-19 15:51:11.272: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 14% free 6651K/7688K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
>
> 11-19 15:51:11.272: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 14% free 6651K/7688K, paused 4ms, total 5ms
>
> 11-19 15:51:11.324: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 14% free 6651K/7688K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
>
> 11-19 15:51:11.332: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 14% free 6651K/7688K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
>
> 11-19 15:51:11.400: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 14% free 6651K/7688K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
>
> 11-19 15:51:11.424: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 14% free 6651K/7688K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
>
> 11-19 15:51:11.464: D/dalvikvm(1251): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 14% free 6651K/7688K, paused 26ms, total 26ms

This never stops and keeps going on and on until I kill the app in the emulator.

Here is my code

> public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String TAG= MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if(isNetworkAvilable()){
        GetSearchData getSearchData = new GetSearchData();
        getSearchData.execute();
        
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "The network is down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    
}


private boolean isNetworkAvilable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    boolean isAvailable= false;
    ConnectivityManager manager=  (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    
    NetworkInfo networkInfo=manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    
    if(networkInfo !=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        
        isAvailable=true;
    }
    
    return isAvailable;
}




private class GetSearchData extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{
    
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params){
        
        int responseCode=-1;
        try{
            
            URL url=new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=JSON");
            
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            
            connection.connect();
            
             responseCode= connection.getResponseCode();
             
            // Log.i(TAG, "Code: "+responseCode);
            
             if(responseCode== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                 InputStream inputStream= connection.getInputStream();
                 Reader reader= new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                 
                 int nextCharacter;
                 String responseData="";
                 while(true){
                     nextCharacter=reader.read();
                     
                     
                     
                     if(responseCode==-1){
                         break;
                     }
                     
                     responseData+= (char) nextCharacter;
                     
                 }
                 
                 JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(responseData);
                 
                 
                 
                JSONObject jsonObject2= jsonObject.getJSONObject("responseData");
                 
                // JSONObject jsonObject3= jsonObject.getJSONObject("results");
                 
                 JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject2.getJSONArray("results");
                 
                 
                 for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                     JSONObject results = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     
                     String title= results.getString("title");
                     
                     Log.v(TAG, "Result "+i+" : "+title);
                     
                 }
                 
                 
             }
             else{
                 Log.i(TAG, "Wrong Response Code: " + responseCode);
             }
             
            
            
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: "+e);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: "+e);
        }
        
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: "+e);
        }
        
        return "Code: "+responseCode;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

> }

Comment: Can you post the full code, i.e. where are you calling execute()?

Comment: @reactivemobile Ya sorry. I posted the full code now.

Comment: Those Log messages are from the garbage collector, they are unrelated to your `AsyncTask`. Try filtering your Log messages by your tag and see what comes up.

Comment: @RogueBaneling When I filter it using my tag, nothing is displayed

Comment: I sometimes have issues getting `LogCat` to work properly. Try using Log.v somewhere that you know for sure is working properly (ie, your onCreate) so you can tell if the log messages are getting printed properly or not.

Comment: @RogueBaneling  The LogCat was working fine before I started using JSON. I think the problem is with the way I'm retrieving the data using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for making your network call, it should work properly for at least getting the data from the internet and then posting it in the LogCat.

```
public class GetSearchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=JSON";
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try{
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                String responseData = inputStreamToString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                Log.v("OUTPUT", responseData);

                JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(responseData);
                JSONObject jsonObject2= jsonObject.getJSONObject("responseData");
                JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject2.getJSONArray("results");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                   JSONObject results = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   String title = results.getString("title");
                   Log.v(TAG, "Result "+i+" : "+title);
                }

            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is){
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The error was because of something so stupid :'), I somehow wrote " responseCode==-1" in the while break condition instead of "nextcharacter==-1". Now my code works. Thanks again and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: If you are looking at a lot of JSON over LogCat you may find http://lograbbit.com/ helpful. It will pretty print the JSON when you double click the message. [Full disclosure, I am the creator of LogRabbit]